# How come after a few $http requests my web app stops responding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm making a little web app that has a queue on it, my entering queue code looks like so:

Angular:

```
 $scope.leaveQueue = function() {
     $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     $http.post('/user/queue/leave')
     .success(function(data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
          $route.reload(); 
          return $scope.user.inQueue = false;
        };
     });
  }

  $scope.enterQueue = function() {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $http.post('/user/queue/enter', $('#enterQueue').serialize())
    .success(function(data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
         $route.reload(); 
         return $scope.user.inQueue = true;
       }
    });
  }
```

My backend with Node to handle said queues are like so:

```
router.route('/queue/enter')
  .post(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.isLoggedIn) {
      req.app.get('pg').connect(req.app.get('conString'), function(err, client, done) {
         console.log(req.user.user_name, req.body.game, req.body.mode);
         client.query("INSERT INTO queue (user_name, user_game, user_mode, created_on) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
                      [req.user.user_name, req.body.game, req.body.mode, new Date()], function(err, results) {
          if (err) { return res.json({'error': err}) };
          return res.json({'success': 'Entered Queue Successfully'});
        });
      }); 
    };
  });

router.route('/queue/leave')
  .post(function(req, res, nex) {
     if (req.user.isLoggedIn) {
      req.app.get('pg').connect(req.app.get('conString'), function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) { return res.json({'error':err}) };
          client.query("DELETE FROM queue WHERE user_name = $1", [req.user.user_name], function(err, results) {
             if (err) { return res.json({ 'error': err}) };
             return res.json({'success': results});
          });
      });
     };
  });
```

My problem is, if I enter and leave queue one too many times, my requests start to become infinitely `pending` and won't resolve till I restart my `node app.js` I have no idea why this is happening to me everything is returning a response wether there is an error or not so I'm not sure why it just leaves hanging and then works fine after a restart.

I'm not sure what is causing this, I'm new to Angular I'm not sure if I'm using `$http` incorrectly. Any information AT ALL would be nice. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Could you narrow this down first by adding e.g. `console.log` calls before each async call? This way you could easily see what is the call that will eventually not complete. You don't seem to be releasing the `pg` clients back to pool at all (and to me it looks odd to call `connect` on every request but I haven't used `pg`). You also do not return from the route if the user is not logged in, but that is unlikely causing the pending.

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't call `done();` after each client.query so I'm not sure exactly what `done();` does with `node-pg` but it seems to have fixed it and now it works. FOR ANYBODY HAVING THIS PROBLEM ITS A PAIN IN THE ASS SO ILL LEAVE THIS HERE AND WONT DELETE IT

Comment: `done();` call returns the client back to the connection pool as said in the [pooling example](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/README.md#client-pooling)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what a `connection pool` is this is my first app using Postgres (first time ever using it also) normally I use Mongo

Comment: While this is not directly related to your problem anymore, connection pool is a collection of open database connections that are reused. Postgres can handle one query per connection so using one connection only would cause a bottleneck. The pool contains eg. 25 open connections that are handed to those asking, and once done with the query you release the connection back to the pool by calling `done();`. Since you didn't call it, after enough queries all the open connections were reserved and `pg.connect` was waiting for a one to be released back to the pool so it can be given the next caller.